# Cant start php session with angular6

Tags: php, angular, angular6

Am working on an project on angular using php as my backend, but when tried to start a session with my php from my angular its not working, the aim is that when a user registers or logins in, it would take the user to http://localhost:4200/dashboard and if the user should refresh the page, the angular would check the php to check if he has a session, if he has a session, it would keep the user in that http://localhost:4200/dashboard or else it would redirect him. here's my code for data.service.ts

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';
        import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

        @Injectable({
            providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class DataService {
            theurl: string='http://127.0.0.1/testing/php/';
            public isLoggin = false;

            constructor(private http: HttpClient, public route: Router) {}
            setLoggedInStatus(value: boolean){
                this.isLoggin= value
            }
            get isLoggedIn(){
                return this.isLoggedIn
            }

            checkLogin(): Observable<cklogin>{ 
                return this.http.get<cklogin>(this.theurl+'check_session.php');
            }
        }

        interface cklogin{
            status: boolean;
        }
```

And for auth guard, that is auth.guard.ts

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
        import { DataService } from './service/data.service';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';
        import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

        @Injectable({
            providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

            constructor(private serv: DataService, private route: Router, public http: HttpClient){}

            canActivate(
                next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
                if(this.serv.isLoggin){
                    return true;
                }
                return this.serv.checkLogin().pipe(map(res=> {
                    return res.status;
                })); 
            }
        }

        interface cklogin{
            status: boolean;
        }
```

And for the register.component.ts

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { DataService } from '../service/data.service';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Register } from './register';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';

        @Component({
            selector: 'app-register',
            templateUrl: './register.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
        })
        export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
            public submitted = false;
            public setputt: any = '';
            public checham: boolean = false;
            public hasError = true;

            constructor(
                private http: HttpClient, 
                private dataservice: DataService, 
                private route: Router
            ) { }

            model = new Register('','','', 0);
            ngOnInit() { }

            onSubmit(...event: Register[]) {
                this.submitted = true;
                this.http.post<eloike>(this.dataservice.theurl+'signup.php', event[0]).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        if(data.success){
                            this.checham = true;
                            this.hasError = false;
                            this.dataservice.isLoggin = true; 
                            this.route.navigate(['dashboard']);
                            this.setputt = data.message;
                        }
                        else{
                            this.submitted = false;
                            this.setputt = data.message;
                        }
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.submitted = false;
                        console.log("Error", error);
                    }
                );;
            }
        }

        interface eloike{
            'success': 'boolean',
            'message': 'string'
        }
```

for the signup.php

```
        <?php
            session_start();
            require_once 'conn.php';
            $info = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
            if(count($info)>0){
                $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->username);
                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->password);
                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->email);
                $phoneNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->phoneNumber);

                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (username, email, `password`, phoneNumber) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$phoneNumber."')");
                if($query){
                    $_SESSION['checklogin'] = $username;
                    $msg = '
                    {
                        "success": true, 
                        "message": "Data Added Successfully"
                    }';
                }
                else{
                    $msg = '
                    {
                        "success": false, 
                        "message": "Data not added Successfully"
                    }';
                }       

            }
            echo $msg;
        ?>
```

for the check_session.php

```
        <?php
            require_once 'conn.php';

            if(isset($_SESSION['checklogin'])){
                echo '{"status": true}';
            }
            else{
                echo '{"status": false}';
            }
        ?>
```

for the conn.php

```
        <?php
            error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );

            ob_start();
            session_start();
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
            $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'angular');
        ?>
```

When i refresh the http://localhost:4200/dashborad after registering or login, it takes me to the http://localhost:4200. I dont where i made a mistake or why the session is not starting

Comment: Other than the `DataService.isLogin` I do not see anywhere where you are keeping this information, when you refresh the `DataService.isLogin` is set to false, I could have missed it, I think you may want to store it in a cookie

Comment: but i dont want to store it as cookies, i want to get the DataService.isLogin from my php check_session.php

Comment: Maybe you need to add an `ob_end_flush()` or `ob_end_clean()` (can't remember off hand) to the check_session.php script, it looks like you start it in conn.php but don't ever tell php to output anything... forgive me if ob_start doesnt work that way it's been a while since I  made use of it

Comment: Your starting the session twice by the way, maybe this is having an effect who knows

Comment: i have removed session start but still the same thing

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Check server logs, check browser console

Comment: i tried the ob_end_flush and clean, and it didnt work

Comment: theirs no error, its just that the session is not set in signup.php

Comment: There is no session in check_session.php, therefore it cannot be true

Comment: the session is in conn.php which is in check_session

Comment: It appears I cannot figure your code pal, my advice is... only have one session_start(), why is a connection to a database starting a session, rethink the php side

Comment: don't hide errors, you would normally see an error about session already being started

Comment: the connection to db is to submit the login details to db

Comment: im getting nowhere here, good luck

Comment: i removed one session_start() am only using the session in conn.php

Comment: i think the problem is that the session was created in the signup.php but it was created like a normal php variable and not as session thats why i cant access it on another page